# Javascript: returns NaN

Tags: javascript, nan

Since I'm pretty new to programming I decided to do some Javascript exercises like this 'minutes to seconds' converter.

If I understand correctly 'm' isn't a number since it isn't declared anywhere. 
'm' (the amount of minutes) is supposed to be the input of the user. However, if I give 'm' a value (e.g. const m = '0') the user won't be able to change the value of 'm'. 


How can I get rid of the NaN error, (but still enable the user to insert a number)? 
Also, is this a good/correct way to take on this exercise?

```js
const convertMinutes = document.getElementById('convertButton');
const m = document.getElementById('input');

convertMinutes.addEventListener('click', convert);
function convert(m){
    return (m * 60);
}
document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = convert() + ' seconds';
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <label>Convert minutes into seconds!</label>
    <input type="number" id="input">
    <button id="convertButton">Convert</button>
    <br>
    <label id="seconds"></label>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you aren't passing anything into `convert()` as well.

Comment: Your event listener (click handler) calls your function but nothing is being done with the return value

Comment: Are you just wanting to have a default value that isn't NaN?

Comment: Also, why are all of the answers here downvoted?

Comment: @Jacob someone wants to punish all the answerers for answering a question they think should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the value of the element with id input and the parse it as an integer or a float (below we parse it as an integer). For further info, pls have an info [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). Pls check the following snippet:

```js
const convertMinutes = document.getElementById('convertButton');

// Here you get a reference to the DOM element with id input
const input = document.getElementById('input');

// Here you register an event handler for the click event on DOM element with id convertButton 
convertMinutes.addEventListener('click', convert);

function convert(){
   // Here you parse the input as an Int and you multiply it by 60
   var seconds = parseInt(input.value,10) * 60;
   
   // Here you set the actual value to the DOM element with id seconds
   document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = seconds + ' seconds';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <label>Convert minutes into seconds!</label>
    <input type="number" id="input">
    <button id="convertButton">Convert</button>
    <br>
    <label id="seconds"></label>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your simple solution and great explanation! Apparently I don't even need to use return here.

Comment: @Appelpeer15 You are very welcome ! I am glad that I helped !

Comment: @Christos pretty sure it was just some troll. Downvoted every single answer with no comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
const convertMinutes = document.getElementById('convertButton');
const m = document.getElementById('input');

convertMinutes.addEventListener('click', convert);
function convert(){
    const seconds = m.value * 60
    document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = `${seconds } seconds`;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <label>Convert minutes into seconds!</label>
    <input type="number" id="input">
    <button id="convertButton">Convert</button>
    <br>
    <label id="seconds"></label>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to break this into two distinct operations. First, you have your convertMinutesToSeconds function. Second, you have your click operation. When clicking the Convert button, you want it to run convertMinutesToSeconds using the value of the input (user-input) and update the DOM with that number.

So, it's a matter of structuring your code that way. You have all the pieces there right now, just not assembled properly.

```js
// Convert function
function convert(m){
    return (m * 60);
}

// Click handler - runs convert function, appends result to DOM.
function handleClick() {
  const m = document.getElementById('input');
  const minutesValue = m.valueAsNumber;
  const seconds = convert(minutesValue);
  document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = seconds + ' seconds';
}

// Attach clickHandler to the button
const convertMinutes = document.getElementById('convertButton');
convertMinutes.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
```

```html
 


    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label>Convert minutes into seconds!</label>
        <input type="number" id="input">
        <button id="convertButton">Convert</button>
        <br>
        <label id="seconds"></label>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track - since you've attached an event handler there's no need to call `convert()` explicitly (as you do in the last line of your js), just move that portion of the code inside the event handler function. See comments in code for details:

```js
// Create some references to our DOM elements
const convertMinutes = document.getElementById('convertButton');
const m = document.getElementById('input');
const s = document.getElementById('seconds');

// Attach the event listener
convertMinutes.addEventListener('click', convert);

// When a function is fired by addEventListener, it is passed an event parameter i.e.: e.
function convert(e) {
  // Simply check that the user didnt leave m text input blank before calculating
  if (m.value) {
    // Do the calculation and set the value of the DOM element's innerHTML
    s.innerHTML = `${(m.value * 60)} seconds`;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <label>Convert minutes into seconds!</label>
  <input type="number" id="input">
  <button id="convertButton">Convert</button>
  <br>
  <label id="seconds"></label>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the value inside the input element from `m.value`.

```js
document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = convert(m.value) + ' seconds';
```